# Unable to Install Jupyter due to legacy-install-error with psutil package

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, vscode-extensions

I was previously running into environment inconsistencies after downloading tensorflow with `pip` in a conda environment, and after several hours of frustration, decided deleting anaconda/miniconda and python and starting from scratch would be my best option to get python working again (The inconsistencies were causing a plethora of issues with loading other modules like numpy, etc).

After downloading Python version 3.9.10 directly from https://www.python.org/downloads/macos/, I wanted to see if I could start using Python again in a Jupyter notebook in VS Code. When I try to run a simple `print('hello world')` in a python chunk I (unsurprisingly) get the following error:

> Jupyter cannot be started. Error attempting to locate jupyter: Running cells with 'Python 3.9.10 64-bit' requires notebook package.
> Run the following command to install 'jupyter and notebook' into the Python environment.
> Command: 'python -m pip install jupyter notebook -U'

I was pretty much expecting this error, since I knew I had deleted all packages when deleting Anaconda and Python.

However, when I try running `python -m pip install jupyter notebook -U` in the terminal I ultimately get the following error:

> xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
> error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
> [end of output]

> note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
> error: legacy-install-failure

> × Encountered error while trying to install package.
> ╰─> psutil

> note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.

Any help or insight is greatly appreciated! I am on MacOS (M1) if that is useful information.

Comment: Whenever I see that notice it usually means I am trying to use python2 to install a python3 package.  I have never used a mac before, but it's worth checking which on linux means running `python3 pip ...` instead of `python pip ...`

Comment: Ah unfortunately that didn't work either (same error) but it didn't hurt to try. Appreciate the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the python3 distribution that comes with MacOSX Command Line Tools. Well, at least that same error was gone after following these steps.
So, to fix the problem I installed python3.9 (I presume you can change 3.9 to your desired version, e.g. 3.8 or 3.10) using Homebrew.

1. Install Homebrew (to check if it's installed already just type `brew --version` in the terminal):

```bash
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

2. Install python3.9

```bash
brew install python@3.9
```

3. Create your virtual environment

```bash
python3.9 -m venv myvenv
```

4. Activate the virtual environment with `source myvenv/bin/activate`
5. Finally, install Jupyter using

```bash
(myvenv) pip install jupyter notebook
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when installing the Jupyter notebook on MacOS 12.5 M2 chip. It turns out that the error is caused by not having GCC on my mac to run the wheel for installing the psutil package because for some reason I removed my XCode from my Mac. So I installed XCode from AppStore and opened XCode after the installation to agree to its terms and conditions. After Xcode went through the setup process I tried `pip install jupyter` again and it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just opened the XCode, accept the terms and the installation proposed, and tried to install the jupyter again and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be very particular about the version of python installed. I set up a fresh installation on a new box this morning and put 3.11 on there. `pip install jupyterlabs` gave me the same error as you got. I then uninstalled python and installed an earlier version, and now it works.

PS the older version that worked for me is 3.10.8